# Can't find plex media server apis

Tags: java

How to use plex media server APIs in our own application?
Is it possible to get  media url, id, ets.. and use them in our apps?
Guide line didn't mention apis for developers

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the docs, I found this: https://github.com/Arcanemagus/plex-api/wiki/Plex-Web-API-Overview.

It looks like they have a bunch of RESTful endpoints.